# adb keeps getting out of date

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I'm using `adb` with the wireless feature to run my app on multiple devices. I know the IP addresses of my devices and run `adb connect x.x.x.x` each time I want to run the app on a new device.

The thing is that when I run `adb` it randomly kills it (`adb server is out of date. killing...`), which disconnects all the previously connected devices. It means that if I have 3 devices connected and want to connect a fourth one, if the server gets killed I have to reconnect the 3 other devices, its rather painful. It may come from Android Studio as I connect the devices using a temrinal and run the app from Android Studio.

Is there a solution to disable the server killing if it goes "out of date" ?

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend that you check your system time and Update your Android Studio and SDK up to date.
I will also recommend you but it is not related to question that you should connect adb using usb as it gives you a advantage.

EDIT:
just use:
adb kill-server
,adb start-server

it may be caused by other running application on your pc disturbing the working of adb

Comment: The system time was a good idea but it's correctly set on my system. Everything is obviously up to date, too. Connecting using usb will fix my issue but I'd rather not as I don't have enough cables for all my devices, and I don't want to turn my PC into an octopus. Having wireless debugging is very convenient to me for this

Comment: Concerning you edit : the thing is that I don't want to kill the server, and it currently gets killed for no reason. It's functionning properly and suddenly it gets out of date and is restarted out of nowhere, that's the problem